# Code appears to be assigning when it should just be reading values

Tags: javascript, datetime, if-statement

So I have this code:

```js
var shotTime = this.lastShot;
  shotTime.setMilliseconds(this.lastShot.getMilliseconds() + this.shootGrace);
  console.log(shotTime);
  console.log(new Date);
  console.log(new Date()>shotTime);
  console.log("-------------------------------");
if(new Date()>shotTime){
  console.log("##############################");
  this.lastShot = new Date();
}
```

This produces this output:

```
Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:44 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 true
 -------------------------------
 ##############################
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 false
 -------------------------------
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:46 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 false
 -------------------------------
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:46 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:46 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 false
 -------------------------------
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:47 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 Mon Mar 12 2018 20:35:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
 true
 -------------------------------
 ##############################
```

This is rather odd as this.lastShot appears to be changing while false while it should only change when true. I can't figure out why there is this change.

Thanks,Ed.

Comment: this.lastShot is not defined

Comment: All variables are defined earlier in the code, would require a lot more code show.

Comment: then define this.lastShot as it would be to display the output you pasted. If there is other code which makes this bit of code not work without it, how can we fix this?

Comment: Sorry I don't under stand what you're saying.

Comment: The code you pasted does not output what you say it does.

Comment: Their defined in the constructor as :

Comment: this.lastShot = new Date();
  this.shootGrace = 500;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166712/discussion-between-ed-lynch-and-george-campbell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shotTime = this.lastShot;
```

When you do this, you're not making a copy.  You now have two references to the same Date object.  Changing one of the references will now affect both.  When you change shotTime, you're changing this.lastShot as well. Do this as a test:

```
var shotTime1 = new Date();
console.log(shotTime1.getMilliseconds());
var shotTime2 = shotTime1;
shotTime2.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(shotTime1.getMilliseconds());
```

And you'll see the second one is zero because shotTime1 and shotTime2 both reference the same Date object.